# Saving image to SQLite

Tags: iphone, sqlite, uiimage

Following code i am Writing to store image in DB.

```
NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"INSERT INTO slamDetailsTable (name, gender, phone,email,movie,abt,dob,smiley1,smily2,smily3,image) VALUES (\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",?)", contact.name, contact.gender, contact.phone,contact.email,contact.movies,contact.abtMe,contact.dob,contact.smiley1,contact.smiley2,contact.smiley3];
        NSLog(@"query %@",insertSQL);
        const char *insert_stmt = [insertSQL UTF8String];

        sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, insert_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL);
        sqlite3_bind_blob(statement, 1, [contact.imageData bytes], [contact.imageData length], NULL);
        if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
        {
            NSLog(@"Row added");
        } 

        else {
            NSLog(@"Failed to add row");
        }
```

Following line i am adding to get image.

```
NSData *imageDataFromDb = [[NSData alloc]initWithBytes:sqlite3_column_blob(statement, 11) length:sqlite3_column_int(statement, 11)];
```

But. imageDataFromDb showing 0 bytes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use `sqlite3_column_int()` to get the length of the blob. The correct call to use is `sqlite3_column_bytes()`.

> If the result is a BLOB or UTF-8 string then the
>   sqlite3_column_bytes() routine returns the number of bytes in that
>   BLOB or string.

Comment: Shoud i use qlite3_column_bytes() for both case?

Comment: @Shreedhar As far as I can see without testing, your write looks ok, it's just that when you're reading, you'll get the length wrong if you use sqlite3_column_int (which will try to convert your blob to an integer, whatever that would return)

Comment: @Shreedhar Since I can't see the query, there are a few things to double check; Is the blob actually the 11'th column coming out of the select? If you log imageData.bytes and length at the insert, do they show what you expect? Are other values correct from your select? Besides the sqlite3_column_int(), I can't see anything strange in the brief code you posted.

Answer (score 0):

While you've asked to do something rather specific, I've always found that storing the image on the device and storing the name or location of that image in the database is a much more efficient way of doing this. Storing large images in a SQLite database can be very time consuming to get.

Comment: Can u get me any example of that kind?

Comment: Not right now, google how to store files to the device and then just store the string of that file in the db. The main problem with this is you might also want to check if the file actually exists. You can either include the images in the application bundle or download them within the app itself.